# DoubleBinding working with Bindings.format() but not bind()

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

So I'm probably missing something obvious here but I have a class which has a method which returns a DoubleBinding of its instance variables:

```
public DoubleBinding getTotalBinding(){
        DoubleProperty h = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100);     //100
        DoubleProperty a1 = baseValueProperty();              // Base
        DoubleProperty aib = itemModifierBaseProperty();      // Item base change
        DoubleProperty aip = itemModifierPercentProperty();   // Item percent change
        DoubleProperty atb = titleModifierBaseProperty();     // Title base change
        DoubleProperty atp = titleModifierPercentProperty();  // Title percent change
        DoubleProperty abb = buffModifierBaseProperty();      // Buff base change
        DoubleProperty abp = buffModifierPercentProperty();   // Buff percent change

        return Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> a1.add(aib.add(atb.add(abb))).multiply((h.add(aip.add(atp.add(abp)))).divide(h)).get()
        );
    }
```

Now when I used this binding to bind to a text node:

```
total.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f", attribute.getTotalBinding()));
```

This works fine, and the text node is updated whenever any of the properties are changed. However if I try to do a similiar binding to another SimpleDoubleProperty:

```
getSomeSimpleDoubleProperty().bind(attribute.getTotalBinding());
getSomeSimpleDoubleProperty().addListener(event -> {
                System.out.println("Something changed");
            });
```

This doesn't work and won't trigger the listener when changing the attribute. However if I bind to some random singular property of the attribute:

```
getSomeSimpleDoubleProperty().bind(attribute.itemModifierBaseProperty());
```

This will update fine. So the total binding works when it's used in Bindings.format(), but not just .bind(). Could someone explain to me why it fails to work and identify a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding in the dependancies in the DoubleBinding constructor.

```
return Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> a1.add(aib.add(atb.add(abb))).multiply((h.add(aip.add(atp.add(abp)))).divide(h)).get(),
                a1,aib,aip,atb,atp,abb,abp
        );
```